# Typescript Have the type of the property from an object

Tags: typescript

I am trying to do a generic react form reducer. For that "Value" must have the type of T by "name". Im not sure to be comprehensive so here is an example that will be clearer:

Example:

```
type RandomObject = { test1: number, test2: string, test3: string[] }

type ActionChangeInput<T> = {
  name: keyof T
  value: typeof T["name"] // Get type of name
}
```

I want value to be a number because value of name is "test1" and "test1" type is number.

```
const a: ActionChangeInput<RandomObject> = {
  name: "test1", // type is "test1" | "test2" | "test3"
  value: 12931 // Expect number here
}
```

Sorry if it's not clear but it's hard to explain something I don't understand (that's why im here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is for `ActionChangeInput<T>` to resolve to a union of all possibilities. You can do that with a mapped type that maps over each property of `T` and creates type that pairs name and value types for just that property.

Something like:

```
type ActionChangeInput<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    name: K
    value: T[K]
  }
}[keyof T]
```

This maps over each property in `T` with `[K in keyof T]`, and creates an object type for each combination of `name` as `K` and value as `T[K]`.

You then index that resulting object by it's own keys to get a union of its values.

With the `RandomObject` type, that should resolve to:

```
type RandomObject = { test1: number, test2: string, test3: string[] }

type Test = ActionChangeInput<RandomObject>
/*
| { name: 'test1', value: number }
| { name: 'test2', value: string }
| { name: 'test3', value: string[] }
*/
```

So any valid value of that type must have a `name` and value type that match in that list of unions.

The rest now behaves as you would expect:

```
type RandomObject = { test1: number, test2: string, test3: string[] }

// fine
const a: ActionChangeInput<RandomObject> = {
  name: "test1",
  value: 12931,
}

// error
const b: ActionChangeInput<RandomObject> = {
  name: "test2",
  value: 12931, // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQQMZgJYHsB2BhAFgQ0wHMYBJTKAVzAB4AVAPjgF44BvUOOAbQGk5UmOAGsYEdADM4dALoAudpy5xM+ALYwFvJVwBu+ADaVN0vjKUBfUBe6jxU2aFCRYcAEqEAJujUB5AEYAVjAoLOxwYDAAzmAAjAqYlGr+MABOADQR0WAATAoxqYJEmZExAMz5YIXE3DJwViCgAPRNcBKCMKBIWDFw+ArIaFh4hCTkVLQemN5+QSFgTKwcIFyqGgoARKVxG+lK+kYmsTkAnGWxeyANza1pqeipXT1gcP4DKBg4BMRkFNQ0UxmAWCKEWihWKnUJi22Ryu32hmMCmOZwucBa0mg8AA5IlkmlsQIoip0C98FEoqgiKp-AZ4GB0BEsXBsQUitiAHQAChyZRyOQAlNYgA)